# Split one column (string) from csv file into three

Tags: php

This probably was asked millions of times, but I can't find a proper answer, really.

Basically, I have a huge .csv file to download data from and to insert it into a local one. It has 10 columns, and the third one is just a string, which always has the same "type" of string. something like: 123/45K67.

I just want to split it into three columns: 123, 45, K67 and exclude the slash totally.

Sorry for bad formatting, writing from mobile.

Comment: A simple way (*if it's the same type of string*) would be to regex it: `preg_match("/(\d{3})\/(\d{2})(\w\d{2})/", "123/45K67", $matches);` (*Super basic example, you could clean the regex up*) - [**Example**](https://tehplayground.com/4AOpMsdysB5TewPx)

Comment: yh, I knew the wording will be bad from me.
(argh! shift + enter sent the message too early).
it is always like 123/45K67, but can be 111/40K60, etc. only constants are / and K here, length of the string is always the same and splits are always for 3 chars, 2 chars and 3 chars

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be:

```
$array = preg_split( "/(?=K)|\//", $value);
```

this returns:

```
array(3) { [0]=> string(3) "123" [1]=> string(2) "45" [2]=> string(3) "K67" }
```

using lookahead to include the matched character, here further information:

http://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html

Comment: hm, I think this is what I am looking for, but! what about including K letter in [2]? with it that's the perfect answer